# How to instantly auto-save newly published Facebook posts of a friend?

Tags: facebook, backup

My Facebook friend's posts are often hacked into, altered and even removed by a government's special services proxy to suppress his speech and for other political reasons. Is there some other way to auto-save & backup his new Facebook posts instantly after they're published?

Comment: Where is he located that you believe the government is editing/removing his posts?

Comment: One would hardly believe this, but Israel

Comment: If the government really was controlling his posts, he would be unable to post. The posts would never be able to be seen at all, instead of first appearing, then being deleted.

Comment: Your friend might look into [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com). There are a number of ways to "re-broadcast" one's Facebook posts (to Twitter, Google Drive, Evernote, etc.). I don't think you can set up a recipe to capture someone else's posts, though.

Comment: Al E., thanks. I'll look into it.